# Deployd :: Failed To Start MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, deployd

I am a beginner in Deployd and MongoDB. I have installed Deployd ([www.deployd.com](http://www.deployd.com)) 0.6.9 on my Windows-XP system. I executed the following command at the prompt as instructed by the book am studying

```
> dpd create sportsstore
```

Now, when I run the following command

```
> dpd –p 5500 sportsstore/app.dpd
```

To start the Deployd server, I get the following error:

```
starting deployd v0.6.9...
Failed to start MongoDB
```

It states that MongoDb has failed to start. I went into the directory `"C:\Program Files\Deployd\tools"` and found that there is a file called `"mongod"`.

I have never installed MongoDB before on my computer. It is my first time working with Deployd so I don't know whether the `"Mongod"` file in the tools folder is the same as MongoDB or I have to install MongoDB separately on the computer.

What can I try next?

Comment: "I have never installed MongoDB before on my computer" - go install mongo on your computer.

Comment: Wondering why deployd is even needed here. Typically I only use on something like a linux container that lacks an initd. On windows you can just use the services to run mongod in the background. But really this question seems a lot more suited to [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) aside from the near obvious "have you even [installed MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)" response, so voting to close.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Deployd is needed because i want to run the Deployd server and MongoDB is not starting

Comment: The job of `deployd` is to run and control "daemon" processes (in Unix terms). Under Windows that is what the "services" control is for. Read the MongoDB windows installation link. You seem to be following a tutorial or reference that is giving you false information.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Deployd (www.deployd.com) is a server used to create APIs. I need to run that server and open its dashboard in my browser to create the APIs. it uses MongoDB. It is this MongoDB am trying to make it work. Maybe you are talking about a different Deployd

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to install mongodb in your computer. You can do it from the official site for MongoDB. The standard option would be to install the Community version.

After that, you can check if mongodb was properly installed and can be used with Deployd:

If you are in iOS or Linux you can try:

```
sudo dpd
```

If you are in Windows try opening a command window with "Run as Administrator" and try:

```
dpd
```

Comment: First of all, you have to install mongodb in your computer. :D

Comment: `sudo dpd` helped me to run it. It seems, that dpd can start mongod couse of root rights..

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Installation.

1) Run `npm install deployd -g`

2) Install Mongo DB separatetly using windows installer available on 
https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community

and configure to run it as service as mentioned on below url. 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Service option is convenient to start and stop database using net start and net stop command

3) create a deployd module using 'dpd create abcd'.

4) navigate to deployd module you have created (using cd abcd) to run `dpd -d command`.  Before you run `dpd -d` command you need to ensure the you start the mongodb service from same command prompt running in elevated mode or admin mode.( use the command : 'net start MongoDB')

In case It is still giving path error  then try below command:
`set path=%PATH%; "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4.1\bin"`

this command is alternative for setting path in environment variable (in case user doesn't have permissions to modify environment variable)

Still not working, same path issue ??
run using command --mongod as mentioned below

dpd -m "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4.1\bin\mongod.exe"

Comment: you have to start mongod.exe service separately. Then try dpd

Answer (score 0):

After installing `deployd`, run:

```
dpd -e production
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem of "failed to start MongoDB":

1. I installed MongoDB for Windows from this web page (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/).
2. Then I created a path as shown below

   [image: path]
3. I installed the deployd and I run:

   ```
   dpd -e production
   ```